# Strong wifi signal but no internet connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

My wifi router is in my living room. I can use internet fine in the living room, but when I move to my bedroom, the internet connection becomes very choppy. It frequently becomes unresponsive, then I have to turn off wifi and and reconnect again. **Even though the signal is strong!**

This happens to both my laptop, my phone and my ipad. There are only 3 devices so it can't be because the wifi router is overloaded. Since it occurs on 3 different devices, I dont think it's the issue of any of the devices.

How do I approach this issue?

Comment: How precisely did you establish that the signal is strong?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz by looking at the bar.... what is a good way to measure it?

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate the make/model of your WAP.

Answer (score 1):

First, what brand are your laptop and phone? Apple products are known to be bandwidth hogs.

You could try to change the channel and or frequency of the WiFi. And it is possible that something in that room could be causing interference and distorting the signal.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a number of things - the best guess being interference from other AP's your phone can hear in the bedroom, but not in the living room.

If one of your devices runs android, Download "Wifi Analyser" and have a look at the various networks  available in each location and their strengths to test this theory, and consider changing the AP frequency or moving the Access point so its more centrally located and thus giving you a stronger signal.

Another possibility (which is not nearly as likely) is that the AP signal is amplified but your devices are only sending a weak signal back to the AP, causing packet drops and slowdowns in your connection.